# Duplicate geometry column in geometry_columns

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table with one geometry column. When I connect it to QGIS I see two of the same column:

[image]

If I make a request in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name = 'mmune'
```

I can see, my view `geometry_columns` have two columns

[image]

I try to run function `Populate_Geometry_Columns` but the result is the same

```
SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns('public.t_adm_commune'::regclass);
```

I try to redefine the column but the result is the same

```
ALTER TABLE mmune ALTER COLUMN geom type Geometry(Multipolygon,2) USING geom::Geometry(Multipolygon, 2);
```

If I question the tables `pg_class` and `pg_attribute` I see once column, that's ok.

Have you got any idea ?

Comment: Which version of postgres `select version();` and postgis `select postgis_version();` are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Comment: Postgis : 2.3 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: I am facing the same problem (postgres 12.4, qgis 3.12, postgis 3.0).

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be caused by geometries with different Spatial Reference (SRIDs) in the same column. The QGIS-Data-Browser will create a layer for each distinct SRID in the geometry column. You can query the SRIDs of a geometry column with the following statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(geom) from mmune;
```